# How to make nested sticky headers with React Native SectionList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to find a creative way to have nested `SectionList`s with section headers. Here's the basic setup:

```xml
<SectionList
  sections={this.sectionData}
  stickySectionHeadersEnabled
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <SectionList
      sections={_.groupBy(item, data => data.date)}
      stickySectionHeadersEnabled
      renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderData(item)}
    />
  )}  
/>
```

While this setup renders well, the inner section headers do not stick, likely due to the fact that that specific `SectionList` does not have a defined height, so the list does not "know" where to stick.

Here's a screenshot, where the **gray** header sticks, but the white headers do not.

[image]

I'm racking my brain for a clever way to implement this, but cannot come up with anything at the moment. Any help or insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? An issue was created for this exact problem on react-native's GitHub repository https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20390 , but it went stale. I'm having the exact same problem, but no solution yet.

Comment: @ErikHaiderForsén unfortunately never did -- if you figure something out I'd love to know too

Comment: Still having this problem :( added a bounty

Comment: This guy has a-lot of great videos might give you an idea of how to do this. (https://youtu.be/4Pw4du1IrDs)